# Do I Need a Class if I only need 1 Property (at the moment)?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, class

Update: I didn't make it clear but I meant this to be a question about where/how I would use a function to return a list of strings when I'm trying to just work with classes.

I have a class called Account.

I have data access class called AccountDAO.

I have various functions that return lists of objects like GetAllAccounts, GetAccountByID etc.

I want to populate a drop down list with just the account names and nothing else. It's proving rather slow when using lists of objects and databinding them to the dropdownlist.

I feel like I should be using a simple "Select Account_Name From blah" type statement and returning a list of strings but I don't know how to work this into my class and data access class.

How should I handle this predicament?

Comment: How big is the Account object? Objects lists are quick so that shouldn't be an issue to use in general.

Comment: @Kirk it's very small but will grow and grow as time goes on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list of string,s and bind the list of strings to a dropdownlist no problem... the DDL can support that, just leave out DataTextField and DataValueField props, and it will display the account name as is, which that name would be accessible through the ListItem's Text and Value property.

I like to use objects to be consistent with the rest of the app (which other areas might need a class), and if for some reason you want to add AccountKey later, if you use an object, all you need to do is add a property.  Otherwise, if using strings, you'd have to switch up the binding later to point to the object.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong by making a function that only returns a list of strings. YOu could however wonder if it's not better to restrict the number of records you want to put in the list and use some kind of paging.

Comment: I'm trying to work out where I put that function in the Accounts class, that's my problem. It's one of those situations where I should work out paging for it but the project went live last week and I'm just plugging holes at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're using a `List<>`, you can try something like this:

```
IEnumerable<string> nameList = accountList.Select(t => t.AccountName);
```

Or if you need a `List`:

```
List<string> nameList = accountList.Select(t => t.AccountName).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Go with your feelings. Use a datareader to select the list and then load them into an arraylist which can then be bound to the dropdown. Alternately, use something like this method I use to provide both a DisplayMember and a ValueMember which uses a class (with both values) as members of the arraylist. This should give you the general idea. (Note: I normally include this code in a data access class (MyBase) where StartReader, _datRdr, ReadNext and_ReaderValid are a members. But the general idea is intact.)

```
Public Sub LoadDataSource(ByRef PlantDataSource As PlantSource, Optional ByVal Filter As String = "", Optional ByVal IncludeBlankItem As Boolean = False)

    PlantDataSource = New PlantSource
    If IncludeBlankItem Then
        PlantDataSource.Add(0, "")

    End If
    If Filter = String.Empty Then
        Call StartReader(" Order by PlantName")
    Else
        Call StartReader(String.Concat(" Where ", Filter, " Order by PlantName"))

    End If

    If _DatRdr.HasRows Then

        While MyBase._ReaderValid
            PlantDataSource.Add(PlantId, PlantName)
            ReadNext()
        End While
    End If
    Call CloseReader()

End Sub

Private Class PlantListing

    Private _PlantList As New ArrayList

    Public Sub Add(ByVal PlantId As Integer, ByVal PlantName As String)

        _PlantList.Add(New PlantDataItem(PlantId, PlantName))

    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property List() As ArrayList
        Get
            Return _PlantList
        End Get
    End Property

End Class

Private Class PlantDataItem
    Private _PlantId As Integer
    Private _PlantName As String

    Public Sub New(ByVal pPlantId As Integer, ByVal pPlantName As String)
        Me._PlantId = pPlantId
        Me._PlantName = pPlantName
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property PlantName() As String
        Get
            Return _PlantName
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property PlantId() As Integer
        Get
            Return _PlantId
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property DisplayValue() As String

        Get
            Return CStr(Me._PlantId).Trim & " - " & _PlantName.Trim
        End Get

    End Property

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String

        Return CStr(Me._PlantId).Trim & " - " & _PlantName.Trim

    End Function

End Class
```